# Typescript Type "Object does not satisfy the constraint 'extends TE' for type parameter

Tags: generics, types, constructor, typescript, extends

Before publishing an issue, I would like to know if it is programmation error or a compiler bug.

Typescript 1.4 (running in Visual Studio 2013) complains on the following small program:

```
export class TE {
  value : string;
}
export class A<T extends TE> {
}
export class B extends A<TE> {
  constructor(public name: string) {
     super(); // Error: Type Object does not satisfy the constraint extends TE for type parameter T.
  }
}
```

The same in screenshot :

[image: real typescript test]

and if I remove the super() clause, it gives:

[image: second typescript test]

A related question is [Type T does not satisfy the constraint C for type parameter P error in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18523133/1287856) but it does not deal with the constructor.

What should I to to make the little snippet above to compile?

Comment: No problems here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: Compilaton does not cause problem if I run it directly. But this error keeps appearing in my editor and I would like to get rid of them for readability and for my collaborators as well.

Comment: no problem here in VS2013/TS1.4 either

Comment: I have VS2013 and I realized that TS1.0 was installed. I switched to TS1.4. But now not only the problem is the same, but there is no syntax highlighting anymore. Thank you anyway for trying out. I'm glad it does not cause problems in at least one place.

Comment: Make sure that you've got TypeScript updated every where in your path as well on your machine. `where tsc` for example from a command prompt (developer command prompt) will show you where it might be found. In earlier versions, I routinely would have 3 or 4 distinct locations unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @WiredPrairie I checked and it's located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.exe`

Answer (score 0):

It compiles fine on the playground :

[image]

And Visual studio and command line:

[image]

Comment: Well it's nice I saw that, so why is it throwing errors on my machine it's something I would like to know. Perhaps it's just resharper.

Comment: Perhaps. Try disabling it.

Comment: Yes, but before disabling ReSharper please create an issue in YouTrack, so that we'll know about the problem and will be able to fix it. :) Thanks! I created an issue for this problem, will be fixed in 9.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-432550

Comment: I re-checked in on fresh 9.1 build, the problem is gone. You're welcome to try a 9.1 EAP build: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.1+EAP.